# Does anybody know how to resolve the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" error when working with pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I wrote a spark app that queries all of the data from a hive table (100M rows, ~ 3GB), collects all of it back to the driver through converting it into a pandas data frame, loops through each record and performs a calculation and saves the result in a new field. Running against a subset of the data completes fine but doing so against the population results in the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" error. The driver has more than enough memory to handle this data as well as a limited # of copies. The driver has about 125GB of memory available and I set driver memory on the job to 32GB. Can anyone assist?

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('some_app').getOrCreate()

    sdf = spark.sql("SELECT * from some_database.some_table") # input
    df = sdf.toPandas() # input converted
    results = pd.DataFrame() # output

    for i in df.some_field.unique():
        df2 = "apply some logic"
        results = results.append(df2) # store processed data in results

    sdf2 = spark.createDataFrame(results)
    sdf2.registerTempTable("sdf2")
    spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS some_database.my_results")
    spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_database.my_results STORED AS PARQUET as select * from sdf2")
```

Comment: try to avoid parsing sdf to pandas df. it probably accounts for OOM.

Comment: On the other hand, did you increase the executor memory ?

Comment: I am not sure it can be avoided because my code loops through the data set. As I understand it, looping cannot be done in spark without first collecting the data to the driver, which is what I am doing with the conversion to pandas. Because I am using just the driver to process the data, I do not think raising executor memory will make a difference since I am only using the executors to query a table at the start of my job. What I did try was increase driver memory but I ended up with the following error now, "java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available".

Comment: Please update your question, adding what you tried above

Answer (score 0):

As the error said this operation consumes too much memory because 3GB data is being read to driver. The real memory footprint will be much more than 3GB, I assumes 5-10X. This is not an appropriate design as it depends on processing power of the driver alone.

You should create the dataframe based on Hive table "some_database.some_table" without converting to pandas.